# I want to count detected strings in file with grep, excluding a specific phrase

Tags: grep

Hi I'm trying to search a log file for the following words and assign the number of matches to a variable as a number.

```
errors
error
fail
failure
can't
```

But I don't want to match the words error or errors if its preceeded by "No "

So ignore error if its "no error" and ignore errors if its "no errors"

Here's what I have so far

```
ErrorCheck=$(grep -vi "No errors" $LOGFILE | grep -ciE "error|fail|can't" $LOGFILE)
```

Its not working out for me unfortunatly, any suggestions would be great.

PS I'm using microcore running busybox shell, so I have a slightly lean environment to work in.

All comments and suggestions welcome.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you change the program that writes the logfile?

Comment: @remus it would be better if you add sample logfile and show the output you got vs what you expect... as such saying not working doesn't tell us what is going wrong and no sample to test the code against...

Comment: Your Right, sorry about that. Here's a sample of the email logfile that is sent after the backup occures. -- Hmm can't seem to get the content in here, theres a limit.... Here's just one line thats a problem ( No errors detected in compressed data of /mnt/hda1/temp/*****.zip ) So, my check is finding ( No errors ) as a positive. I'd post all the code from my shell script if I could figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think one problem is that the "-v" flag for grep will basically omit the entire line containing 'No errors' or any other string you specify. So if a single line contains both "no failures" and "can't" for example, you'd have a problem.

One possible (sort of janky) way to do this could be to store values in three different variables: NUM_COUNTED minus NUM_NOTS = ErrorCheck, which should account for having a "no failure" and an actual failure indicator in the same line.

```
NUM_COUNTED=grep -ciF 'error
fail
can't' $LOGFILE
NUM_NOTS=grep -ciF 'no error
no fail' $LOGFILE
ErrorCheck=`expr $NUM_COUNTED - $NUM_NOTS`
```

Alternatively, this seems to be giving (mostly accurate) results:

```
ErrorCheck=$(grep -vi 'No errors' $LOGFILE | grep -ciF 'error
fail
can't' $LOGFILE)
```

The -F flag just tells grep to look for string literals (error, fail, and can't) which are newline separated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've had no luck with RegEx solutions so far... Turns out the mistake in my original code which was `ErrorCheck=$(grep -vi "No errors" $LOGFILE | grep -ciE "error|fail|can't" $LOGFILE)` and should be `ErrorCheck=$(grep -vi "No errors" $LOGFILE | grep -ciE "error|fail|can't")` has gotten it working. Another problem I just discovered is that busybox aka ash shell does not seem to support lookbehinds, lookaheads, lookarounds in grep.